# Python split binary data buffer into specific sized chunks and store them in variables

Tags: python

I have below code:

```
tag_and_data = bin_file_obj.read(chunk_size)
```

And then I segregate it into two variables based on some byte size (first 16 bytes for tag and rest all for data) using **slicing** as below:

```
tag, data = tag_and_data[16:], tag_and_data[:16]
```

Can I do the above in one-line? Is there any built-in method like **split**() to fragment the data based on byte size and unpack them into variables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built-in solution, but you would write:

```
def decompose_tag_and_data(tag_and_data):
    return tag_and_data[16:], tag_and_data[:16]
```

and then call it like:

```
tag, data = decompose_tag_and_data(bin_file_obj.read(chunk_size))
```

There's an obvious an obvious extension to:

```
def decompose(data,index):
    return data[:index],data[index:]
```

but extending that to support more than one index in a pythonesque way is beyond me.